# How to show progress bar while git clone repo?

Tags: python

I am cloning the git repo into my addon folder.
I want the operator to show the progress of the cloning of the repo.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
import os


class XX_OT_install_dependencies(Operator):
    bl_label = 'Install Dependencies'
    bl_idname = 'xx.install_dependencies'

    def execute(self, context):
        import subprocess
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '../')

        subprocess.run(['cd', path], check=True)
        subprocess.run(['git', 'clone', '<repo>'], check=True)

        return {'FINISHED'}


classes = (
    XX_OT_install_dependencies,
)

register, unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)
```

Comment: I think you'd have to setup a pretty elaborate boilerplate structure if you want to send and receive messages between processes that way. Happy to be proven wrong though. Also if I may is it a "the client wants it that way so I must do it" requirement or is it a "I'm bored waiting for it to complete, wouldn't it be nice to have a progress bar showing me how much left I have to wait" requirement ? Because if it's the latter, the combined time you'll spend setting this up will far outpass the amount of time you'll save by looking at the progress bar filling up :p +1 though